# Proof of Probability Inequality for Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

So I came across this claim (presented without proof) in a text I am reading. I believe that is true, although I have made little progress in proving that this is so.

> Let $Y$ be a random variable on$(Ω,F,P)$such that $E(Y^2)<∞$. 
>   Let $X$ be a random variable and $Z=\ \unicode{x1D7D9}(X∈B)$ for some boreal set $B$.
>
> Then $$E[Y−E(Y|X)]^2≤E(Y−Z)^2$$

I tried to simplify the right hand side, but could not get further that $$E(Y^2)-E[2Y(E(Y|X)]+E[E(Y^2|X)]$$
Then the last term is $E(Y^2)$ by law of iterated expectations. So then we have $$2E(Y^2)-2E[Y(E(Y|X)]$$

I can not see how this can be simplified any further. Am I approaching this wrong? I think the claim is true, but have thus far been unable to prove so.

Comment: That should be: $~\mathsf E[(Y-\mathsf E[Y\mid X])^2] ~{= \mathsf E[Y^2]-2\mathsf E[Y\mathsf E[Y\mid X]]+\mathsf E[\mathsf E[Y\mid X]^2] \\ =\mathsf E[Y^2]-\mathsf E[\mathsf E[Y\mid X]^2] }$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $E[E(Y|X)E(Y|X)]$ which equals $E[E(Y^2|X)]$? Even if not, I am unsure how that would help?

Comment: No, $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)^2 ~\neq~\mathsf E(Y^2\mid X)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just took an exam on this.......

$$\begin{align} \mathbb E [Y-Z]^2 =&\mathbb E[(Y-\mathbb E[Y\vert X])+(\mathbb E[Y\vert X]-Z)]^2\\=&\mathbb E[Y-\mathbb E[Y\vert X]]^2+2\mathbb E [(Y-\mathbb E[Y\vert X])(\mathbb E[Y\vert X]-Z)]+ \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\vert X]-Z]^2\\
\end{align}
$$
consider the second term:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E [(Y-\mathbb E[Y\vert X])(\mathbb E[Y\vert X]-Z)]&=\mathbb E \{\mathbb E [(Y-\mathbb E[Y\vert X])(\mathbb E[Y\vert X]-Z)\vert X]\}\\
&=\mathbb E \{\mathbb E [(Y-\mathbb E[Y\vert X])(\mathbb E[Y\vert X]-I_{\{X\in B\}})\vert X]\}\\
&=\mathbb E \{(\mathbb E[Y\vert X]-I_{\{X\in B\}})\mathbb E [(Y-\mathbb E[Y\vert X])\vert X]\}\\
&=\mathbb E \{(\mathbb E[Y\vert X]-I_{\{X\in B\}})(\mathbb E [Y\vert X]-\mathbb E[Y\vert X])\}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
so 
$$\begin{align}\mathbb E [Y-Z]^2 &=\mathbb E[Y-\mathbb E[Y\vert X]]^2+ \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\vert X]-Z]^2\\
&\geq \mathbb E[Y-\mathbb E[Y\vert X]]^2
\end{align}
$$
since the last term cannot be negative.